# Clarification in Struts 2

Tags: java, javascript, struts2, struts

There is a page in which there are multiple rows with a 'Change Status' button[a 'submit' button] at the end of each row. There are more than ten status present. When I click on the 'Change Status' button, the control goes the action class and the page reloads with the changed status.

I have id's associated with each row. how do I identify in which row I have clicked the 'Change Status' button when the page reloads ? Should I pass the id through java-script to the action class ? Is there a simpler way than this ?

Comment: is change status is a submit button?

Comment: Yes it is a submit button.Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can take advantage of Struts2 multiple submit button functionality.Like you can set submit button value based on your ID and collect that in your action to use it in your way something like

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" name="buttonName">
<button type="submit" value="Clear" name="buttonName">


class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
   private String buttonName;
   public void setButtonName(String buttonName) {
      this.buttonName = buttonName;
   }
   public String execute() {
      if ("Submit".equals(buttonName)) {
         doSubmit();
         return "submitResult";
      }
      if ("Clear".equals(buttonName)) {
         doClear();
         return "clearResult";
      }
      return super.execute();
   }
}
```

So in short value can be what is the uniqque id and you can use it in action as per your choice
for details

- [multiple-submit-buttons](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/multiple-submit-buttons.html)

Comment: It's not really a submit button. It's a html link,on clock of which,  I am submitting via javascript. So I don't think we can use this thing. Do we have anything similar ?

Comment: if its a link than i believe you can add that id to the link to send it as a query string

Comment: yeah Ok. But on return to the same web page, how do I figure out the proper status box and populate it ?

Comment: your question in that case is not very lrea and u can  set any flag in ur action class

Answer (score 0):

You can add the id to be part of your form and that way you will receive the id as a parameter  when you submit. No need for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a different form for each row.
Every form can have a

```
<s:hidden />
```

with the id of the row.
In this way you always know which is the submit clicked.